Chimney water leak
we have a damp issue around the chimney breast in our front bedroom. To try to resolve, we had a roofer come out and inspect. Without even getting up on the roof, he stated by looking from the roadside that he knew what the problem was. Some fifteen years ago, we had a builder re-build the stack as it was in a bad state of dis-repair. This roofer stated that it required covering of the bare brickwork with some type of mortar. That evening it rained and washed the rear side off from the Chimney. He came back and put some more rendering on. Along with placing a new "crown" on. This hasn't stopped the damp, it seems to have made it worse. We have now noticed that some of the rendering has came off the rearside again. Can you please advise the best way forward?

A) We can't see anything from here, so sharing some pics would be helpful. B) You took the advice of the first guy who came along?
